Required Fields Based on other Field in React, Yup and Formik
I have a problem requiring the account_id field when mode_of_payment has a value.
My code below still doesn't make the account_id required when mode_of_payment has been filled out. mode_of_payment isn't a required field but when you fill it out, the account_id should become required
import { array, boolean, object, string } from 'yup';

const validationSchema = object().shape({
  remarks: string().nullable(''),
  remittance_items: array().of(
    object().shape({
      id: string().nullable(),
      mode_of_payment_id: object().shape({
        id: string().nullable(),
        name: string().nullable(),
        with_bank_details: boolean(),
      }),
      account_id: object().shape({
        id: string().when('mode_of_payment_id.id', {
          is: (id) => !!id,
          then: string().required('Select an account'),
          otherwise: string().nullable(),
        }),
        name: string().when('mode_of_payment_id.id', {
          is: (id) => !!id,
          then: string().required(''),
          otherwise: string().nullable(),
        }),
      }),
    })
  ),
});


Try something like this -
import { array, boolean, object, string } from 'yup';

const validationSchema = object().shape({
  remarks: string().nullable(''),
  remittance_items: array().of(
    object().shape({
      id: string().nullable(),
      mode_of_payment_id: object().shape({
        id: string().nullable(),
        name: string().nullable(),
        with_bank_details: boolean(),
      }),
      account_id: object().shape({
        id: string().when('mode_of_payment_id', {
          is: (mode_of_payment_id) => !!mode_of_payment_id?.id,
          then: string().required('Select an account'),
          otherwise: string().nullable(),
        }),
        name: string().when('mode_of_payment_id', {
          is: (mode_of_payment_id) => !!mode_of_payment_id?.id,
          then: string().required(''),
          otherwise: string().nullable(),
        }),
      }),
    })
  ),
});


Issue is still the same :(

Can you tell what error you are getting in console. Are you using formik?

No errors.  mode_of_payment here is undefined ---> is: (mode_of_payment_id) => !!mode_of_payment_id?.id,

Can you share github link?
